# Swipe page in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

I am new in this section. I searched and what i get is `view pager` for swipe pages.

Could anybody tell me how could i make perfect swipe and which technique should i use.

Here is the [link](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) which i get

```
<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

I have the following doubts:

Using `Viewpager` can i swipe pages?

Here is the image what i want to do:

[image]

If i can, then could i do this in `every direction`

@Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think [jFeinstein's SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) is just what you need. I've use it many times and compared to the rest I've tried, it's the best choice for me.

Although you can try the [Sliding Layer from the 6wunderkinder team](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib), haven't tested it but seems really nice visually ;)

Answer (score 0):

Swiping ViewPager you can vist it:

[viewpage](http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need Fly menu.. There are many open source library available for it..
You have a look at [this one](https://github.com/Espiandev/FlyInMenu)..